# Google Plus Screenshare

Tags: web, native, google-plus

I was hoping that someone knows a little bit more about Google Plus's in-browser screensharing capabilities. The flow obviously is:

- Download some sort of native plugin
- Visit the website
- Some magic
- Bam! There is screenshare

What exactly is going on with the plugin that is downloaded? Where can I look to build a system that works similarly?

All online resources point to taking a screenshot of a person's screen and creating a MJPEG, and we all know that's no fun.